# How could I interpret the following message received by a webserver?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, server, client

I recently started working with the python socket and ssl packages.
As an part of a exercise I connect to a webserver that uses a self signed ssl connection to apply a man-in-the-middle attack, capturing exchanged messages. After I send a message I wait for a response like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
self.wrapped_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
self.wrapped_socket.connect((self.tcp_ip, self.tcp_port))

data = self.wrapped_socket.recv(4096)
```

The returning message of the server (data) always consists random digits. Up to a sent message string of the length 4 the returned value matches the length, but for message lengths greater than that it never exceeds 4.
Example for "hello": b'0460\n'

Does anyone have an idea how I could interpret this? Has it something to do with the ssl wrapping, is it some kind of hashing or is just a hint of the exercise to apply further actions like an replay attack?

Right now I'm stuck in interpreting these ressources and I would appreciate any help or hints.